# Quarkus logging with Datadog

Tags: logging, quarkus, datadog, jboss-logging

In Quarkus, the default logging library is JBoss and using the `quarkus-logging-json` allows you to encode your logs as JSON.

However, Datadog integration requires custom fields such as `service`, `dd.span_id` and `dd.trace_id` to have the logs associated with the correct syntax.

Currently, I've tried adding this in `application.properties`:

```
quarkus.log.console.format=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5p service=%X{myServiceName}, traceId=%X{dd.trace_id}, spanId=%X{dd.span_id} [%c{2.}] (%t) %s%e%n
```

However, this seems not to show up in Datadog as expected.

When we use log4j2, we simply configure it like so.

```yaml
Appenders:
  Console:
    name: Console_Appender
    target: SYSTEM_OUT
    JSONLayout:
      KeyValuePair:
          - key: service
          value: myServiceName
```

Again, cannot find any documentation how to accomplish the same result in Quarkus configs.

Does anyone know how I could inject these custom properties into the JSON logs with Quarkus or how to integrate it with Datadog properly?

Answer (score 2):

I think the disconnect here is that the pattern needs to be in the Jboss log manager, and then they're encoded to JSON.

Have you tried putting `%X{dd.trace_id:-0} %X{dd.span_id:-0}` into your Jboss logging pattern?

If not, I'd also recommend opening a ticket at support@datadoghq.com and we can work this through with you.